# Курсор сдвигается в текстовом поле на начало

Tags: java, html, css, text

Как отключить с помощью CSS или html автоматический сдвиг курсора на начало в текстовом поле, если поле обновилось и в нем есть текст? Т.е. есть поиск по таблицам в веб приложении, который работает через ajax и не требует нажатия кнопки. Реализовано с помощью Java, wicket. Когда я ввожу текст в поле, после ввода каждого символа, курсор прыгает на начало и таким образом не дает нормально ввести текст. Что предложите?Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, где-то используется коварный метод setText() для поля ввода. А используется он для фильтрации ввода, наверное, или чего-то подобного.

Предложу в реализации поля ввода после окончания фильтрации и установки значения перемещать курсор на позицию равную длине текста.

Может [тут](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/33771-peremeshhenie-kursora-v-konec-polya-vvoda-ochen-prosto.html) или [тут](https://toster.ru/q/91193) Вы найдёте решение на чистом html и css, на js оно описано выше.

На JS примерно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/j0sLhL2v/) будет выглядеть функция:

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var input = document.querySelector("input");
  var len = input.value.length;
  input.setSelectionRange(len,len);
  input.focus();
});
```

Для такой вот формочки:

```
<input value="Lorem Ipsum">
<input id="btn" type="button" value="OK">
```